# Sort documents by closest to current date mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I cannot figure out how to sort the documents from the closest date to current.
My model looks something like this:

```
...
  when: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
...
```

This is what I tried:

```
MatchModel.find({when: { $gte: new Date() }})
```

Comment: If your schema has the option of  [**`timestamps`**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) to true then you can easily able to `$sort` with it.